# How to order columns of two merged dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I merged two dataframes and I export them to excel file
I'd like to reorder merged columns, I tried some solutions but without success

At the moment I get this output:

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga8NT.jpg)

But my goal is to get this one:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmTyd.jpg)

This is my code (just dataframes):

```
    df = df[['home','away','scorehome','scoreaway','result','best_bets','oddtwo','oddthree', 'sum_stats', 'over05', 'over15', 'over25', 'over35', 'over45', 'goal', 'esito', 'tournament', 'uniquefield']]

    df2 = df2[['home2','away2','htresult','shresult','result2','tournament2', 'uniquefield2']]

print(pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='uniquefield', right_on='uniquefield2', how='left').drop('uniquefield2', axis=1))
df3 = df.merge(df2, left_on='uniquefield', right_on='uniquefield2', how='left').drop(['uniquefield2', 'tournament2', 'home2', 'away2', 'result2'], axis=1) 
df3 = df3.sort_values(by=["home","away","scorehome","scoreaway","htresult","shresult","result","best_bets","oddtwo","oddthree", "sum_stats", "over05", "over15", "over25", "over35", "over45", "goal", "esito", "tournament", "uniquefield"])

# determining the name of the file
file_name = 'BexDataFull.xlsx'
 
# saving the excel
df3.to_excel(file_name)
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reordering columns is as simple as re-selecting them in the correct order. I think you are currently trying to do it with this line

```
df3 = df3.sort_values(by=["home","away","scorehome","scoreaway","htresult","shresult","result","best_bets","oddtwo","oddthree", "sum_stats", "over05", "over15", "over25", "over35", "over45", "goal", "esito", "tournament", "uniquefield"])
```

But that's wrong, you are sorting the values with this, not the columns.

Change it to this and you are good.

```
df3 = df3[["home","away","scorehome","scoreaway","htresult","shresult","result","best_bets","oddtwo","oddthree", "sum_stats", "over05", "over15", "over25", "over35", "over45", "goal", "esito", "tournament", "uniquefield"]]
```